# Point Azure webroot to different folder

Tags: node.js, azure

I've set up an NodeJS website on Azure to continuously deploy from github. Unfortunately my github project is structured in a way that the root isn't the website.

```
github_root
|_ app(nodejs website)
|
|_ docs
|
|_ blah
```

It seems that Azure(IIS) is looking for server.js in the github_root.

Is there a way to point IIS to the 'app' folder for the website?

Comment: Maybe you can use the custom deployment script. I'm not sure if it helps but you might have a look  http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1

Comment: yup you are right. Using Kudu deployment script I could tell it to use the app/ folder as site directory to deploy. If you add your comment as answer I will accept

Answer (score 2):

Node.js applications deployed on Windows Azure with IIS server use [`iisnode`](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) - native IIS module that allows hosting of node.js applications.

You can specify which file is you main application file in `web.config` e.g.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <!-- // configure your node.js application file here -->
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="your_application_file.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>

        <!-- ... // other configuration parameters .... -->

    <system.webServer>
<configuration>
```

You can find more examples (including URL rewriting etc.) on Tomasz Janczuk's ([iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) creator) [blog](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/).

I hope that will help or gives you right directions.